# Returning Response while doing a background process in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using spring boot to process a huge excel file. As it`s a time-consuming process, I want to return total number of records (as response) before my file is processed (after the file is processed I return the records as response). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get total rows using Apache POI .

```
            File file = new File(filePath);
            XSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
            XSSFSheet myExcelSheet = myExcelBook.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow headerRow = myExcelSheet.getRow(0);
            
            int totalRows = myExcelSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
```

`totalRows` returns total number of rows in the excel sheet.

> ### Edited

You can use two method calls for doing the same .

```
String file="/path/to/file";
int count=getExcelRecordCount(file);
Records records= getActualExcelRecords(file);
```

Comment: I want to return totalRecords as response at first and after the file is processed, return all the records.

Comment: you can use two method calls for achieving your goal .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like spring batch would be a good idea. Your first step would check the # of rows in the file by importing the data & counting the number of instances of a unique identifier. Or if you know the delimiter (pipe |? comma ,? ) & the # of expected columns, you could just count the # of delimeters in the file and divide that by the number of feilds (or columns) and you  have the # of rows.

In your next spring batch step you could do the rest of the processing.

Hope this is helpful, Pioneer!

Have fun with Boot! its very opinionated imo, but useful if you and spring both want the same things haha.